# $.get does not violate Same Origin to GAS... why?

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, same-origin-policy

Why does $.get work cross domain to Google App Scripts (i.e. why is it not blocked by the same origin policy of the browser)?

For example, I set up a very simple script on Google App Script (GAS):

```
function doGet() {
return ContentService.createTextOutput('Hello, world!');
}

function doPost() {
return ContentService.createTextOutput('Hello, world!');
}
```

and then in the browser from a page hosted by a DIFFERENT DOMAIN (lets call it www.example.com):

```
var url = "{url of my google app script}";
$.get( url, function( response ) {
            console.log(response);
});
```

and it works!!  But it should not.  I get the page from example.com and in it I request data from the google app script (which is hosted on a different domain by google).  Why is this cross domain access allowed and not blocked by the same-origin policy?  I'm am NOT using CORS or JSONP.

If, instead of using $.get in the browser, I use:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false); // false for synchronous request
xmlHttp.send(null);
console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

I get an error as expected.

I'm totally confused.  Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this by executing `$.get('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw0e1JgXXH6F1f1R_9ZKNQ5wPNcNOPfK7rNW68ohyWIvf0pDiI/exec', function(r) {console.log(r);});` in the console on this very page. Got the error 
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.. etc"

Comment: Actually.. I just tried a GET request to the google app script using Postmon.. and looking at the reply headers... I see: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"... Does that mean that GAS support CORS now?   Doesn't "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"  mean that any site can access this script cross domain?